# JSON.NET: Getting nested value when key contains dots?

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to access a nested value with JSON.NET. I know I can use the `.SelectToken()` method to access a nested value (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39337136/2698119) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42290485/2698119)). My issue is that the JSON I'm trying to access has keys with dots in them:

```
var json = @"
{
  ""data.dot"": {
    ""value"": 5,
  }
}";

var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(jo.SelectToken("data.dot.value")); // <-- doesn't work
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer while writing this question, so I might as well share my findings.

It turns out that the `.SelectToken` method is very powerful, and:

- [allows you to query a JSON with escaped properties](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm) by surrounding your key with `['{key}']`
- [allows you to use regex](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/RegexQuery.htm)
- [allows you to filter by path value](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/StrictEqualsQuery.htm)
- [allows you to query by complex path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

So in my case, I could write:

```
jo.SelectToken("['data.dot'].value"); // escaped property
jo.SelectToken("$..value"); // complex JSON path
```

I could also use the `JToken` indexer, but contrary to the `.SelectToken` method, it would throw an exception if the JSON doesn't contain the `data.dot` key:

```
jo["data.dot"]["value"]
```